# Plotly: Error when using the "ticklabelposition" argument

Tags: python, plotly, axes

I'm trying this script from Plotly's website (https://plotly.com/python/axes/), but I get an error when changing the tick label position in the y-axes

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks(indexed=True)-1
fig = px.bar(df, x=df.index, y="GOOG")
fig.update_yaxes(ticklabelposition="inside top", title=None)
fig.show()
```

Error Message:

```
ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.layout.YAxis: 'ticklabelposition'

Did you mean "ticklabelmode"?
```

The code works fine when taking out the "fig.update_yaxes()" function.

I appreciate if someone could give me feedback on how to solve this.

Comment: works for me, plotly 4.14.3

Comment: Thank you Rob. I updated tue plotly version and now it works

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, this is very likely a version issue. I'm on `'4.14.3'` too and your *exact* code snippet works fine on my end:

[image]

Comment: Thank you vestland. I updated the plotly version and now it works